# How to capitalize attribute when fetching it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, getter

my users write their first and last name without capitalization

Is there a way to overwrite the getter of `firstname` and `lastname` attributes of the `User` model such that it will return `firstname.capitalize` ?

if I do

```
def firstname
 self.firstname.capitalize
end
```

I get `stack too deep error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the same name as the attribute, you need to use read_attribute

```
def firstname
  read_attribute(:firstname).capitalize
end
```